# ¿Es más eficiente usar " string.clear() " o " string = ' ' "?

Tags: c++, optimización

¿Es más eficiente usar `string.clear()` o en cambio sería más optimizado si uso `string = ''` para vaciar el contenido de un String?

¿Debería siempre usar la función de la librería (`string.clear()`) o la más "simple" (`string = ''`) como mejor práctica?

Comment: ¿mejor para quién?

Comment: para el compilador. agregare esa ultima linea para ser mas claro

Comment: El compilador no tiene sentimientos. Ninguno de los dos es mejor o peor para el compilador.

Comment: ¿entonces no hay dieferencia entre ambos?¿ni para `string` con mas de 100 caracteres?

Comment: Si que hay diferencias, pero tu pregunta no es qué diferencias hay, sino cuál es mejor, y mejor, sin decir en qué sentido, se convierte en algo subjetivo. Lo que a mi me parece mejor, puede no serlo para alguien más, y tampoco puede resultar lo mejor para un proyecto particular dependiendo de sus requerimientos/necesidades/objetivos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usando `string::operator=()`, ocurre lo siguiente:

1. Se genera una cadena vacía en la sección de datos, para poder obtener su dirección.
2. Se genera código para pasar su dirección a `string::operator=()`
3. `string::operator=()` leerá la dirección que se le pasa, para obtener el tamaño de la cadena que se le pasó como argumento.
4. El operador hace su trabajo.
5. El operador devolverá un resultado.

Recordemos que la clase `std::string` es *dueña* de las cadenas que maneja: cuando se le asigna un valor, *copia* la cadena a un bufer interno, para hacerla independiente de la cadena original.
Esto conlleva cierta gestión de memória, y la *necesidad* de conocer el tamaño de las cadenas que se les asignan.

Usando `string.clear()`, ocurre lo siguiente:

1. Se llama a la función `string.clear()`,  sin argumentos, y esta hace su trabajo.
2. No se devuelve nada.

Por supuesto, aquí entran en juego las optimizaciones de cada compilador, pero, en general, **es mejor llamar a funciones específicas que utilizar mecanismos genéricos**.

**EDITO**

Una implementación típica, incompleta y sin plantillas, solo como ejemplo didáctico, sin ser exhaustiva:

```
class string {
private:
 char *buffer;
 size_t alloc; // Tamaño del buffer.
 size_t length; // Longitud real de la cadena.

public:
 string &operator=( const char *other ) {
  size_t other_size = strlen( other ); // Tamaño de la cadena a asignar.
  if( other_size <= ( alloc - 1 ) ) { // Utilizamos un byte para el 0 al final.
   // La nueva cadena cabe dentro del buffer.
   if( other_size != 0 ) // la nueva cadena no está vacía.
    memcpy( alloc, other, other_size + 1); // La copiamos, incluido el 0 final.
   length = other_size; // Nueva longitud de la cadena.
   return *this;
  }
  /*
   ... Resto de la implementación ...
  */
 }
 inline void clear( ) {
  length = 0;
  *buffer = 0; // un 0 al final, por si acaso.
 }

 /*
  ... Resto de métodos ...
 */
};
```

Se cumple a rajatabla el *standard*:

- El tiempo de ejecución de `operator=()` es lineal (depende de la
  longitud de la cadena *other*).
- El tiempo de ejecución de `clear()` es siempre el mismo. En el *standard*, se especifican comportamientos *de máxima duración*, es decir, `clear()` cumple con el *standard*, puesto que lo mejora.

Si observamos el código de ejemplo:

```
string &operator=( const char *other ) {
 size_t other_size = strlen( other );
 . . .
```

Lo primero que hacemos es obtener el tamaño de la nueva cadena. **Ese** es el punto critico, ineludible. Tenemos que saber el tamaño **si** o **si**.
Esa llamada a `strlen( other )` es la culpable de que `clear()` sea mucho más rápida.

Aún obviando el tiempo de colocar y sacar elementos de la pila, la función `clear()` es mucho mas rápida que + `operator=()`.
Es más, aún teniendo en cuenta prácticamente cualquier optimización posible (colocar cadenas pequeñas *in-place* dentro del puntero para ahorrarnos gestión de memória, ...), la función `clear()` *casi* siempre será más rápida, porque se ahorra comprobar tamaños. Puede haber casos en los que asignar una cadena vacía sea *igual* de rápido que `clear()`, pero serán contados y altamente dependientes del compilador y la implementación.

Especulando un poco, y entrando en *masturbaciones mentales*, el único caso que se me ocurre en el que ambas sean equiparables en velocidad, es que el compilador tenga optimizaciones concretas para el caso de cadenas vacías, y la implementación de string las conozca y sea capaz de utilizarlas (un tipo propio, similar a *nullptr*, para indicar un puntero a una cadena vacía). Y no será aplicable en todos los casos.

Resumiendo, y como dije antes, **es mejor llamar a funciones específicas que utilizar mecanismos genéricos**.

Comment: Se agradece la corrección, pero no estoy de acuerdo con añadir un punto a la lista de acciones al llamar a string.clear( ). La llamada a una función se puede resumir en 3 pasos: colocar argumentos en la pila, realizar la llamada, y sacar el resultado de la pila, tal y como hace string::operator=(). string.clear(), sin argumentos y sin retorno, obvia los puntos 1 y 3 anteriores. Es por ello por lo que coloqué un solo elemento en su descripción.

Comment: Lo añadí únicamente por coherencia ya que en el caso de la asignación separaste el trabajo dentro de la función y la devolución de la misma. En cualquier caso la corrección es meramente estética. El marcado en gris está pensado para destacar código ya que suele incluir resaltado de sintaxis y añadir texto plano puede provocar que la respuesta sea menos legible. En cualquier caso nada te impide volver a editar la pregunta para dejarla a tu gusto... al fin y al cabo eres el autor de la misma :)

Comment: No veo que la función `clear` de tu ejemplo de implementación de `string` borre los datos solicitados ¿has hecho algún benchmark incluyendo `delete [] buffer` en el `clear`?

Comment: ¿ Y para que quiere borrarlos, si pone un \0 en el primer caracter y marca la longitud como 0 ? con eso es suficiente. El buffer se guarda para futuros usos hasta que la instancia sea destruida. Es la implementación mas básica de todas. Las mas modernas usan el propio puntero para guardar la cadena, si cabe, y se ahorran la gestion del buffer si, por ejemplo, solo la usas para guardar una "".

Answer (score 1):

Según la documentación disponible en cppreference sobre el [operator =](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) y la función [clear](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/clear) tenemos lo siguiente:

#### `std::basic_string::operator =`

1. `basic_string& operator=( const basic_string& str )`: Complejidad lineal dependiente del tamaño de `str`.
2. `basic_string& operator=( basic_string&& )`: Complejidad lineal dependiente del tamaño de la cadena (`this`) ya que cada uno de los caracteres reservados deben ser borrados.
3. `basic_string& operator=( const CharT* s )`: Complejidad lineal dependiente de la longitud de la cadena apuntada por `s`.
4. `basic_string& operator=( CharT )`: Complejidad constante.
5. `basic_string& operator=( std::initializer_list<CharT> sv)`: Complejidad lineal dependiente del tamaño de `sv`.

Complejidad lineal significa que el coste de computación crece linealmente según el parámetro, es decir: cuanto más ocupe el parámetro más coste de computación tendrá. En otras palabras, si asignar cada caracter del parámetro costase 0,0001 segundos se tardaría 1 segundo en asignar una cadena de 10.000 caracteres.

Complejidad constante significa que el coste de computación es el mismo independientemente de los parametros sobre los que se opere.

#### `std::basic_string::clear`

La complejidad de esta función es lineal dependiente el tamaño de la cadena a borrar. Es decir: si borrar cada caracter del `string` costase 0,0001 segundos se tardaría 1 segundo en borrar una cadena de 10.000 caracteres.

#### `string.clear()` contra `string = ' '`

Para empezar ambas funciones hacen cosas diferentes. `clear` borra el contenido de la cadena (pasa a estar vacia y tener una longitud de 0 caracteres) mientras que `string = ' '` asigna el caracter espacio a la cadena (pasa a contener el caracter espacio y longitud de 1 caracter).

Una vez aclarado esto, vemos que estás usando la sobrecarga 4 del operador `=` de `std::string`, el único cuya complejidad es constante. Dependerá de cuán costosa sea esa complejidad constante para saber si es más o menos costosa que borrar la cadena pero sin duda, existirá un tamaño de cadena cuyo borrado será más costoso que usar `string = ' '`.

#### ¿Qué dice el estándar?

A mi personalmente no me cuadra que asignar un caracter sea de complejidad lineal; así que he consultado sus requerimientos en el [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (la traducción es mía):

> #### 21.4.2 `basic_string` constructores y operadores de asignación
>
> `basic_string& operator=(charT c);`
>
> devuelve: `*this = basic_string(1,c)`.

Parece que para asignar un caracter, se construye un `string` temporal el cuál después se asigna al `string`, así que se usará el asignador de movimiento (sobrecarga 2) cuya complejidad es lineal dependiendo del tamaño del actual `string` pues hay que borrar los contenidos antiguos.

#### Concusión.

`string.clear()` y `string = ' '` hacen cosas diferentes pero tienen un coste de computación muy parecido pues ambas funciones deben borrar el contenido anterior, escoger uno u otro dependerá de si quieres acabar con una cadena vacía o con una cadena con un espacio.